# How to insert a table inside Word's column?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I have a Java application and creating a MS Word document which has a two-columns section. I need to insert a lot of tables in this columns.
I am not bounded to Apache POI, I need ANY Java solution, but in Apache POI I am creating two-columns document this way:

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166883/how-to-add-continuous-section-break-to-xwpfdocument/41188851#41188851
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578288/apache-poi-multiple-columns-in-a-word-docx-document
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("One column on top. ");
        CTSectPr ctSectPr = paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewSectPr();
        CTColumns ctColumns = ctSectPr.addNewCols();
        ctColumns.setNum(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
        paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        run=paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+ "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , "+
                "тестируем перетекание текста между колонками , ");
        run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
        run.setText("2тестируем перетекание текста между колонками  ");
        ctSectPr = paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewSectPr();
        ctSectPr.addNewType().setVal(STSectionMark.CONTINUOUS);
        ctColumns = ctSectPr.addNewCols();
        ctColumns.setNum(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
        ctColumns.setEqualWidth(STOnOff.OFF);
        CTColumn ctColumn = ctColumns.addNewCol();
        ctColumn.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(4500));
        ctColumn.setSpace(BigInteger.valueOf(300));
        ctColumn = ctColumns.addNewCol();
        ctColumn.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(4500));
```

and the subject is to insert a lot of tiny tables inside XWPFRun (or some other method) please tell me how to insert tables into a columns? Now this job doing by macros, and I need to get rid of this, do everything inside JVM. Thank you!

Comment: You seems not have understood how section settings work. I have described it more verbose in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166883/how-to-add-continuous-section-break-to-xwpfdocument/41188851#41188851 now. All **above** the paragraph having two-column-section-settings will be in two columns. That includes tables too.

Comment: Sorry it is unclear. Section breaks in the single column when I doing XWPFTable supergroupTable = document.createTable();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code uses only one `XWPFRun` splitted into two columns. A `XWPFRun` cannot contain tables. But sections can contain all document body elements, not only text runs. That also includes `XWPFTable`s.

A section contains all body elements between two paragraphs having section settings or from last paragraph having section settings up to end of body. There the section settings are be effective upwardly. Section settings in a paragraph is effective for the body elements above that paragraph. And the section settings in body is effective for  body elements from end of body upwardly up to last paragraph having section settings.

Complete Example having table in left and right column of a two columns section:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.BreakType;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.Borders;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDocument1;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTBody;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTColumns;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTColumn;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDocGrid;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STDocGrid;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STSectionMark;

public class Word2ColumnPageWithTables {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("One column on top. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  //paragraph with section settings for one column section above
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  CTSectPr ctSectPr = paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewSectPr();
  CTColumns ctColumns = ctSectPr.addNewCols();
  ctColumns.setNum(BigInteger.valueOf(1));

  //left column

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The left side");
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. ");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Table on left column:");
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(1,2);
  table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setText("Cell A1");
  table.getRow(0).getCell(1).setText("Cell B1");
  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  // right column 

  //paragraph with column break
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.addBreak(BreakType.COLUMN);
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The right side");
  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. ");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Table on right column:");
  table = document.createTable(1,2);
  table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setText("Cell A1");
  table.getRow(0).getCell(1).setText("Cell B1");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  //paragraph with section break continuous for two column section above
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  ctSectPr = paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewSectPr();
  ctSectPr.addNewType().setVal(STSectionMark.CONTINUOUS);
  ctColumns = ctSectPr.addNewCols();
  ctColumns.setNum(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
  CTColumn ctColumn = ctColumns.addNewCol();
  ctColumn.setSpace(BigInteger.valueOf(300));
  ctColumn = ctColumns.addNewCol();

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("One column on bottom");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.");

  //section setting continuous for one column section above
  CTDocument1 ctDocument = document.getDocument();
  CTBody ctBody = ctDocument.getBody();
  ctSectPr = ctBody.addNewSectPr();
  ctSectPr.addNewType().setVal(STSectionMark.CONTINUOUS);
  ctColumns = ctSectPr.addNewCols();
  ctColumns.setNum(BigInteger.valueOf(1));

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Word2ColumnPageWithTables.docx");  
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: One more question: how to make XWPFRun alternate with tables to perform this report https://www.picpasteplus.com/index.php?action=images&folder=&image=a489f960cd  ?